# Input validation by regexp in Safari

Tags: regex, html, google-chrome

Modern browsers, including Safari, [support pattern validation on inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), such as:

`<input type="text" pattern="[a-z]+">`

Is using [Unicode Categories](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) somehow special?

Pattern `[\p{L}]{1,100}` doesn't work in Safari, but works in Chrome:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <form>
    <!-- 
    "hello" should be a valid input
    works in chrome 66
    doesn't work in safari 11.1
    -->
    <input type="text" pattern="[\p{L}]{1,100}" name="bar" value="">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `\p{L}` will only work in Chrome right now. It's currently not part of the JavaScript regex engine specs

Comment: It is not the first question and it is becoming alarmingly frequent. Chrome implemented some ECMA2018 features, like Unicode category classes, `s` modifier, named capturing groups, but not other browsers.

Comment: Sorry, but the *Is using Unicode Categories somehow special?* question is too vague. What answer do you expect? (Aha, forgot to add infinite width lookbehinds as the new cool ECMA2018 feature)

Answer (score 1):

### ECMAScript TC39

This is similar to other issues involving Chrome's ability to process lookbehinds in regex, but other browsers being incapable of the same. At the moment, this is part of the Ecma TC39 proposals under [ECMAScript proposal: Unicode property escapes in regular expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes). It is scheduled to be included in ES2018.

So far this has been implemented in Chrome 64, Safari Preview 42 and regexpu (transpiler) according to that link.

There are a couple of workarounds for Unicode properties in JavaScript at the moment (also described in the link). The workarounds do not work for the HTML5 `pattern` attribute.

#### XRegExp

> Use a library such as [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp) to create the regular expressions
>   at run-time:
>
> ```
> const regexGreekSymbol = XRegExp('\\p{Greek}', 'A');
> regexGreekSymbol.test('π');
> // → true
> ```
>
> The downside of this approach is that the XRegExp library is a
>   run-time dependency which may not be ideal for performance-sensitive
>   applications. For usage on the web, there is an additional load-time
>   performance penalty: xregexp-all-min.js.gz takes up over 35 KB of
>   space after minifying and applying gzip compression. Whenever the
>   Unicode Standard is updated, a new version of XRegExp must be
>   published and end users need to update their XRegExp copy in order to
>   use the latest available data.

#### Regenerate

> Use a library such as [Regenerate](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regenerate) to generate the regular
>   expression at build time:
>
> ```
> const regenerate = require('regenerate');
> const codePoints = require('unicode-9.0.0/Script/Greek/code-points.js');
> const set = regenerate(codePoints);
> set.toString();
> // → '[\u0370-\u0373\u0375-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0384\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03E1\u03F0-\u03FF\u1D26-\u1D2A\u1D5D-\u1D61\u1D66-\u1D6A\u1DBF\u1F00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FDD-\u1FEF\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFE\u2126\uAB65]|\uD800[\uDD40-\uDD8E\uDDA0]|\uD834[\uDE00-\uDE45]'
> // Imagine there’s more code here to save this pattern to a file.
> ```
>
> This approach results in optimal run-time performance, although the
>   generated regular expressions tend to be fairly large in size (which
>   could lead to load-time performance problems on the web). The biggest
>   downside is that it requires a build script, which gets painful as the
>   developer needs more Unicode-aware regular expressions. Whenever the
>   Unicode Standard is updated, the build script must be updated and its
>   results must be deployed in order to use the latest available data.

---

I should also add that you can actually drop the `[]` from your regex: `\p{L}{1,1000}`

Comment: It is all good, but the workarounds are not actually helpful in context of HTML5 `pattern` attribute where a simple string pattern is only expected.